# How to choose different fragment for Ecto Query based pattern matching?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Is it possible to pattern match Ecto `fragment`?

- I'd like to add extra fields for my query
- One of them is how many times a particular `Place` was saved by `Visitors` - **it's always the same**
- The second one is pattern matched:

  - I can now upfront if `Visitor` saved a `Place` - `true`/`false`
  - I need to check if `Visitor's` ID is inside a list of `Visitors` IDs who saved this place

Can I do that with pattern matching?

---

```
defmacrop saved_count(place_id) do
  quote do
    fragment(
      "(SELECT count(id) FROM \"saved_places\" WHERE place_id = ?)",
      unquote(place_id)
    )
  end
end

defmacrop saved_by_visitor?(place_id, saved_by_visitor)
when is_boolean(saved_by_visitor) do
  quote do
    fragment(
      "(?)::BOOLEAN",
      ^unquote(saved_by_visitor)
    )
  end
end

defmacrop saved_by_visitor?(place_id, visitor_id) do
  {:ok, binary_visitor_id} = Ecto.UUID.dump(visitor_id)

  quote do
    fragment(
      "(SELECT ? = ANY(array_agg(visitor_id)) FROM \"saved_places\" WHERE place_id = ?)",
      ^binary_visitor_id,
      unquote(place_id)
    )
  end
end

defp add_extra_fields(query, saved_by_visitor) do
  from places in query,
    group_by:  places.id,
    select:    %{places |
                 saved_count:     saved_count(places.id),
                 saved_by_visitor: saved_by_visitor?(places.id, saved_by_visitor)
               }
end
```

The error is with:

```
no match of right hand side value: :error
```

Because I cannot pass `saved_by_visitor` value to a macro directly.

---

EDIT:

I come up to the following:

```
defmacrop saved_by_visitor?(place_id, saved_by_visitor)
when is_boolean(saved_by_visitor) do
  quote do
    fragment(
      "(?)::BOOLEAN",
      ^unquote(saved_by_visitor)
    )
  end
end

defmacrop saved_by_visitor?(place_id, visitor_id) do
  quote do
    fragment(
      "(SELECT ? = ANY(array_agg(visitor_id)) FROM \"saved_places\" WHERE place_id = ?)",
      ^Ecto.UUID.dump(unquote(visitor_id)),
      unquote(place_id)
    )
  end
end

defp add_extra_fields(query, saved_by_visitor) do
  from places in query,
    group_by:  places.id,
    select:    %{places |
                 saved_count:     saved_count(places.id),
                 saved_by_visitor: saved_by_visitor?(places.id, saved_by_visitor)
               }
end
```

but there's still a problem with the guard and pattern matching of course.

Comment: Does the code you've written not work? Does it throw any error? If so, can you please include that in the question?

Comment: Which line threw that error?

Comment: `{:ok, binary_visitor_id} = Ecto.UUID.dump(visitor_id)` because `visitor_id` is passed not as a bare value but a part of an AST.

Comment: Does this work (in your latest example): `saved_by_visitor: saved_by_visitor?(places.id, ^saved_by_visitor)`. (I don't have the complete setup or I would've tried it.)

Comment: Nope, `cannot use ^saved_by_visitor outside of match clauses`